# Convert first order transfer function to c code

Tags: c, function, matlab, transfer, simulink

I have a simple first order transfer such as "3/s+3" or "tf(3,[1 3])" function and I would like to implement in c code. I have a C function that is called with the delta time since the last iteration:

```
double output(double input, double t); //usually, t is around 0.01 second
```

How do implement the transfer function 3/s+3 in C?

Comment: This isn't clear.  Is "5/s+3" in the Laplace domain?  Are you asking how to perform the inverse Laplace transform programmatically?

Comment: I suppose it's in Laplace domain. By the way, that should be `3/(s+3)`, no?

Comment: I edited the question. Yes, it's 3/(s+3) and it's in the Laplace domain.

Comment: @gregoiregentil: Ok, well [there are tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) of standard Laplace identities.  If you have a rational polynomial in `s`, then you can just use partial-fraction techniques, and then you're basically done!

Comment: To say it explicitly, you don't implement transfer functions in the Laplace domain.  That's good for analysis/design/etc, but when implementing we live in the real domain, so you need to convert that TF to an impulse response or difference equation to actually implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just a matter of implementing 3/(s+3) directly.
You need to discretize it to the z-domain using an appropriate technique (forward euler, backward euler, tustin, zero-order hold) then implement the discrete version of the filter.

The following would be a simple version for the Tustin transformation.
As written, the state needs to be initialized and stored somewhere externally to this function.

```
double firstOrderLag(double input, double coeff, double dT, double *state){
// Function to implement the discretization of a continuous time first
// order lag sys = coeff/(s+coeff) using the Tustin (Bilinear) transformation.

    double num = (1/(1+2/coeff/dT)); // numerator
    double den = (1-2/coeff/dT)*num; // denominator
    double temp;
    double output;

    temp = input - den*(*state);
    output = num*(temp + (*state));
    *state = temp;

    return output;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to go via the z-domain?  You can trivially obtain a symbolic representation of the continuous-time equivalent, and then evaluate it at whatever sample rate is required.

Comment: Because your continuous time equivalent sampled at a given sample rate is equivalent to the z-transformation, so why not just go there rather than introduce an intermediate step.

Comment: Only because it seems simpler to use trivial tables of identities than to go via the z-transform!

Comment: Sorry for the necromancy, just thought I'd clear it up: @OliverCharlesworth's reason is that deriving the exact inverse Laplace equation will give exact values, no matter the sampling, while with Z-transform it's only an approximation, as good as it may be -- which needs a reasonably low (depending on the transform) sampling rate, too.